# Can Gradle initialize empty module in Multi project build

Tags: gradle

I know you can do gradle init --type  to initialize some empty folder as a Gradle project. Source: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html

But is there a similar task to create empty module of certain type in an already existing project?
For example I already have Android app and android library module and I would like to add a Java library to that project. I know that you can create empty folder then add build.gradle then declare module in settings.gradle of root and then create all that folder structure that gradle expects but I am looking for a task (even if I need to apply additional plugin to get it) to automate this bootstrapping process.

Comment: There's nothing built-in to Gradle which helps with this. Maybe someone made a plugin, let's see if anyone answers that.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I feared that would be the answer but was hoping just the documentation was not detailed enough. It seemed logical to me to have similar option like when creating submodules in git. I will probably open a feature request for this since I think it will be easy to implement but might also try creating a plugin if noone suggest some existing one.